# Example of decreasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions such that $\int f_n \ d\mu= +\infty \ \text{ and } \ \int f \ d\mu=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a decreasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions which are defined on the interval $[0,1]$ and which converge pointwise to a bounded function $f$ such that
$$\int f_n \ d\mu= +\infty \ \text{ and } \ \int f \ d\mu=0.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx^2}, f(x)=0$ then
$$\int f_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{n}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_0^1 =\infty \quad and \quad \int f(x) dx=\int0dx=0$$